# CSS: почему в «@media» не учитывается переопределённое значение «rem»

Tags: css

Почему `@media (max-width: 50rem)` срабатывает при `800px` (`50 * 16px`), ведь по идее должен срабатывать при `500px`, так как мы его переопределили для `<html>`?

Код ниже, а [вот](https://jsfiddle.net/6wo7Lhfp/) ссылка на песочницу — там сразу можно увидеть, передвигая центральную разделительную линию ...

```css
html {
  /* override `rem` */
  font-size: 10px;
}

div {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .px500 {
    background: green;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 50rem) {
  .rem50 {
    background: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="px500">500px</div>
<div class="rem50">50rem</div>
```

Comment: @media screen and (max-width...)

Comment: Нет, не в этом дело ... https://jsfiddle.net/k0qokn7c/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного разобравшись с сутью вопроса, [согласно спецификации](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#units):

> Relative units in media queries are based on the initial value, which
> means that units are never based on results of declarations. For
> example, in HTML, the ‘em’ unit is relative to the initial value of
> ‘font-size’.

А вот начальное значение шрифта есть middle - это как раз те самые 16px. Поэтому задавая медиа запросами размер экрана в rem и em не самая лучшая идея, честно говоря.
И видимо это "проблема" для Chrome'a.

Answer (score 1):

```
@media only all and (min-width: 160px) and (min-width: 10em)
```

Лучше, пожалуй, писать так.
Пиксели - абсолютная единица, равная 1/96 дюйма (точнее округлённая то целого числа реальных пикселей, конкретного устройство с высокой плотностью пикселей)

em в данном случае ничем не отличается от rem, почему всё же предпочтительней использовать em, честно говоря не помню, скорее всего, поддержка лучше.

Итак, в большинстве браузеров, 1em будет по-умолчанию равняться 16px.
Пользователь, как известно, может менять настройки своего шрифта в браузере, и тогда значение rem изменится.
Но имея значение в пикселях, мы точно уверены в том, что значение будет не меньше определённого минимума, заданного в пикселях.
Зачем же тогда значение в em? Затем, что мы должны быть также уверены, что значение не меньше определённого количества rem, чтоб применить правило, ведь размеры блоков во-первых могут задаваться в rem, но даже если это и не так, то всё равно строчное содержимое может так или иначе влиять на размеры. В результате, правило применится только если содержимое проходит и по пикселям и по rem.
Давайте пофантазируем и представим себе, что у нас "значение по-умолчание" будет не 16px, а 18px. Что изменится? А ничего, кроме того, что переход отобразится чуть позже. В точки "значение по-умолчанию" минимум той функции, которая при изменении rem даёт переход начиная с определённого значения. В одну сторону уменьшится не дадут пиксели, а в другую rem, которых будет больше если значение пикселов по-умолчанию маленькое.
Поскольку дизайн обычно разрабатывается, чтоб работать ОТ такого-то значения, то при "правильном" значении по-умолчанию, у нас всё увеличится в нужный момент, но если мы что-то поменяли, то увеличится "чуть позже", возможно, Вы не увидите часть функциональности, предназначенной для высоких разрешений, но, по крайней мере у Вас всё не съедет...